# How do I change the Tomcat default working directory?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

In my web application, when I do `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`, the path returned is `<tomcat_home>/bin`. I want to change it to `<tomcat_home>/webapps/<app_name>`.

The default directory for HTML `./path` works fine and is the path I want. But the Java path `./Path` is different in the same project.

I have tried to add a parameter like `workDir="Path"` in the `<Host>` area of the `server.xml` file on my Tomcat server, but it doesn't work.

How do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

The general question of how to change the working directory of a java process has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java). The simple answer is that the java language and the java virtual machine don't provide a way to change the working directory of the JVM process. You won't be able to change the working directory after tomcat has started.

Tomcat's startup scripts (bin/startup.sh and so on) don't set a working directory. The tomcat process will normally inherit whatever the current directory was for the startup script. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753663/what-determines-the-current-working-directory-of-tomcat-java-process). To make tomcat start in a different working directory, you'll have to figure out what is launching tomcat, and change that process to change to the desired directory before it runs startup.sh.